# Spring boot package does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am currently learning spring boot and while Maven tries to compile my code, an exception is raised :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] 
/demo/src/main/java/com/springapp/controler/TutorialControler.java:[13,27] package com.springapp.model does not exist
```

I cannot figure out why my classes that are well created and well packaged makes the compilation fail. Here is my pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.27</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried multiple modifications in the pom.xml such as the "groupId" attribute of the project.

Comment: I would suggest to remove this: `<version>RELEASE</version>`...

Comment: @khmarbaise Removing this tag does not work

Comment: Please show the file which produces the issue because the `package com.springapp.model ` seemed to be the problem which does not exist...

Comment: @khmarbaise Here are the imports of the TutorialControler.java file which produce the issue.

```package com.springapp.controler;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.springapp.repository.TutorielRepository;
import com.springapp.model.Tutoriel;```

Comment: The package `package com.springapp.model does not exist` which lead me to the point where you use `com.springapp.model.Tutoriel` which might simply be a typo using `Tutotrial` and I would suggest to use lowercase package names...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use this dependency structure?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.27</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Sometimes order matters I experienced.

Comment: Changing the dependencies order does not work...